# how is it that PDO can have methods with typed string parameters, but I can't do this in my own functions?

Tags: php, pdo, type-hinting

If I create an instance of PDO and then call PDO->Quote('test') it works no problems.

If I look at the defination of the PDO Quote method it looks like this:

```
/**
 * Quotes a string for use in a query.
 * PDO::quote() places quotes around the input string (if required) and escapes special characters within the input string, using a quoting style appropriate to the underlying driver.
 *
 * @param string $string The string to be quoted.
 * @param int $parameter_type Provides a data type hint for drivers that have alternate quoting styles.
 *
 * return string
 */
function quote(string $string, int $parameter_type) {/* method implementation */}
```

Note the parameters actully have types defined in the method signature, string and int.

Now if I create a function like this:

```
function Test(string $test) {
    return $test;
}
```

And attempt to call it like this:

```
echo Test('test');
```

It fails with the following error:

```
( ! ) Catchable fatal error: Argument 1 passed to Test() must be an instance of string, string given, called in [path_removed]TestTypeHinting.php on line 36 and defined in [path_removed]TestTypeHinting.php on line 2
```

How come PDO can do it, but I can't?

Regards,

Scott

Comment: Where did you see that PDO code?

Comment: I am using Visual Studio 2012 and the PHP Tools for Visual Studio extension.  It has intellisence for PHP and also you can right click on a method and choose Go To Definition from the context menu and it will jump to the file that hosts that method.  The file that opened when I did this was:  C:\Users\[accountNameRemoved]\AppData\Local\Temp\137E147D$allphpnet.xml\global$class$PDO.php  and the file tab said: global$class$PDO.php[from metadata]....  like as if it was showing a DLL API...

Comment: Then that's just a type hint that VS supplies so *it* can type hint. It is not the *actual* PHP code.

Comment: hmmm....  I wonder how VS knows that the param should be a string, just from the PHPDoc and maybe they infer it?  I might ask the guys that make PHP Tools and see what they reckon ;-)

Comment: Yes, it's likely auto-generated from the documentation or source.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's documentation and the real code. Read about [type hinting](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.typehinting.php).

> Type hints can not be used with scalar types such as int or string

But there is some moving to implement [scalar type hinting](http://nikic.github.io/2012/03/06/Scalar-type-hinting-is-harder-than-you-think.html).

You can add phpdoc for documentation your function.

```
/**
 * Test function
 * @param string $test
 * @return string
 */
function Test($test) {
    return $test;
}
```

Also read about [How to read a function definition](http://www.php.net/manual/en/about.prototypes.php)

Comment: sectus, thanks for responding.  Yeah I have seen the doco, and based on that I understand why I can't do it, but how come PDO can expose a PHP API that does have a typed string parameter?

Comment: @user2109254, look at added link

Comment: sectus thanks again mate.  So what what I was looking at above, is just documentation describing what you should be passed in, and not actually an accurate representation of the underlying method signature, as in PHP you can actually use type hints on scalar types?
If that is the case they should stick with the standard method documentation format:   * @param string $string The string to be quoted.

Answer (score 4):

Simple scalar types like string and int cannot be used as a type hint. I think the string you saw on pdo was type hinting for humans in the documentation. http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.typehinting.php

**The world has changed**

With the introduction of PHP 7 [scalar type hints](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php#functions.arguments.type-declaration) are now a thing.

Comment: Thanks for responding mate.  I think I get it now.  However I think it is misleading and if it is just doco them then should use the standard PHPDoc format and leave the method signature to adhere to PHP language rules.

Comment: It probably came from a tool like phpdoc.